# IntelliJ - un-excepted format

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there a reason IntelliJ adds `underscore lines` for Scala code?

In this example bellow - IntelliJ is complaining about 'comment':
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjcw9.png)

[Style IDE Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZRef.png)
How to prevent that / fix it?

Comment: These lines indicate a warning. To see what the IDE warns you about, you can hover over the highlighted text.

Comment: Why would IDE warn me about comment? I think it is a 'style' issue with Scala and InteliJ but not sure how to troubleshoot...

Comment: The IDE does warn about different things, including comments. Please hover over the highlighted text to see what the IDE warns you about.

Comment: @yole - added a picture of what is complaining about..

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [ScalaStyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/) integration in IntelliJ IDEA ([ScalastyleCodeInspection.scala](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/idea181.x/scala/scala-impl/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/codeInspection/scalastyle/ScalastyleCodeInspection.scala)).

ScalaStyle is a third-party tool and it's not enabled out of the box - it requires a custom configuration in `.idea/scalastyle_config.xml`.

It should be possible to disable the inspection, as usual: Alt + Enter / Disable inspection, or Settings / Editor / Inspections / Scala style inspection. Aternatively, you may simply delete the `scalastyle_config.xml` file from the project.